# getting unsat core using Z3_solver_get_unsat_core

Tags: z3

suppose that here is the set of constraints on nonlinear real arithmetic like

```
pred1 = (> (- (* (- v2_x v0_x) (- v1_y v0_y)) (* (- v2_y v0_y) (- v1_x v0_x))) 0)
pred2 = (> (- (* (- v1_x v0_x) (- v2_y v0_y)) (* (- v1_y v0_y) (- v2_x v0_x))) 0)
```

In fact, if we do

```c
Z3_solver_assert(ctx,solver,pred1);
Z3_solver_assert(ctx,solver,pred2);
b = Z3_solver_check(ctx, solver);
```

`b` would be unsat. I want to obtain the unsat core (for this example is trivial). So, for each of these predicates I defined a predicate variable. Lets say they are `p1` and `p2`.

```c
Z3_ast p1 = mk_bool_var(ctx, "P1");
assumptions[i] = Z3_mk_not(ctx, p1);
Z3_ast g[2] = { pred1, p1 };
Z3_solver_assert(ctx,solver,Z3_mk_or(ctx, 2, g));
Z3_ast p2 = mk_bool_var(ctx, "P2");
assumptions[i] = Z3_mk_not(ctx, p2);
Z3_ast g[2] = { pred2, p2 };
Z3_solver_assert(ctx,solver,Z3_mk_or(ctx, 2, g));
```

and then I call `Z3_solver_check_assumptions(ctx, solver, 2 , assumptions);`

but this returns `Z3_L_UNDEF` and the reason is `(incomplete (theory arithmetic))`

I am wondering where I am making a mistake and how this issue can be solved.

Here is how things are initialized:

```c
  ctx = Z3_mk_context(cfg);
  Z3_symbol logic_symbol = Z3_mk_string_symbol(ctx, "QF_UFNRA");
  solver = Z3_mk_solver_for_logic((Z3_context)ctx, logic_symbol);
  Z3_solver_inc_ref(ctx, solver);
  Z3_params params = Z3_mk_params(ctx);
  Z3_symbol param_symbol = Z3_mk_string_symbol(ctx, "unsat_core");
  Z3_params_set_bool(ctx , params, param_symbol, Z3_L_TRUE);
  Z3_solver_set_params(ctx, solver, params);
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Z3 contains many solvers. For nonlinear arithmetic problems it uses `nlsat`. The implementation of this solver is located in the directory `src/nlsat`, and the algorithm is explained [here](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/leonardo/files/IJCAR2012.pdf). However, the current `nlsat` implementation does not support unsat core extraction nor proof generation. When unsat core extraction is requested by the user, Z3 switches to a general purpose solver which is incomplete for nonlinear arithmetic. That is, it may return `unknown` for nonlinear arithmetic problems. The general purpose solver has support for many theories, quantifier, unsat core extraction, and proof generation. It is complete for *linear* arithmetic, but as I said it is not complete for the nonlinear fragment. In the plan, Z3 will have a new version of `nlsat` that is integrated with other theories and support unsat core extraction, but this is future work.