# Is calling check twice supposed to work?

Tags: python, z3

See the PyZ3 program at http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/GTYu. The first call to `check()` works fine, but if we add a constraint to the solver and call `check()` again, we get an inconsistent model!

```
sy_i = Bool('sy_i')
s0_v, s1_v, s2_v, sx_v, sy_v = Reals('s0_v s1_v s2_v sx_v sy_v')

c = [s0_v >= 1,
     sx_v >= 1,

     s1_v >= s0_v * sx_v,

     sy_v >= 1,

     Or(Not(sy_i), s1_v == RealVal(0.0)),

     s2_v >= s1_v * sy_v
]

solver = Solver()
solver.add(c)
print solver.check()
print solver.model()

solver.add(True)
solver.check()
print solver.model()
```

Somebody knows what is going on?

The unstable Z3 version gets the same result.

Additional context:

The program is a simplification of a bigger one that uses the combined `nlsat` and `bool` solvers, following the great advice of the answer: [Z3 real arithmetics and data types theories integrating not that well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868156/z3-real-arithmetics-and-data-types-theories-integrating-not-that-well)

Note that the method seems to work very well, but when trying to add more constraints and reuse the solver this problem arises. Maybe it misdetects the solving method?

Comment: note that link only answers are discouraged. your code snippet is really small, you should include it inline in a question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default solver object `Solver()` is essentially a portfolio of solvers. It also tries to detect the usage pattern (incremental or non-incremental). If more than one `check()` is executed, it assumes the user is in "incremental" mode, and uses a general purpose incremental solver which is not complete for non-linear arithmetic.

To force Z3 to always use `nlsat`, we should create the solver object using

```
solver = Tactic('qfnra-nlsat').solver()
```

If we do that, we can still use `push()`, `pop()`, multiple `check()`'s. However, `nlsat` will not "reuse" work from previous `check()` calls. [Here is the new version of your script](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/tyBC).

Comment: Wonderful Leonardo, thank you very much!! [We were suspecting this]

Comment: By the way, is there some more documentation apart from describe_tactics(), for instance it was difficult to know if qfnra-nlsat would work with the bool combination, what is the difference with qfnra-nlsat with nlsat, etc...

Of course we can look into the source code!

Comment: The tactic `qfnra-nlsat` uses the tactic `nlsat`. It applies several preprocessing steps before invoking `nlsat`. It does that because the tactic `nlsat` can only handle formulas in CNF format.

Comment: The following link contains the implementation of `qfnra-nlsat`. It is just combining several existing tactics using combinators http://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/c430fe26aa30#src/nlsat/tactic/qfnra_nlsat_tactic.cpp